# compiling PythonQt with Qt creator

Tags: c++, python, qt, python-3.x, python-3.2

I am trying to compile [PythonQt](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/) using Qt creator but it return me 163 errors.

> C:\Users\Kato\Desktop\Qt projects\PythonQt-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug\src....\PythonQt2.0.1\src\PythonQtStdDecorators.h:46: error: Python.h: No such file or directory

and such other directories.

I have python 3.2 installed and I have changed prf file to be:

```
# profile to include and link Python

# Change this variable to your python version (2.5, 2.6)
win32:PYTHON_VERSION=32
unix:PYTHON_VERSION=2.6

macx {
# for macx you need to have the Python development kit installed as framework
INCLUDEPATH += /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
LIBS += -F/System/Library/Frameworks -framework Python
} else:win32 {
# for windows install a Python development kit or build Python yourself from the sources
# Make sure that you set the environment variable PYTHON_PATH to point to your
# python installation (or the python sources/header files when building from source).
# Make sure that you set the environment variable PYTHON_LIB to point to
# the directory where the python libs are located.
#
# When using the prebuild Python installer, this will be:
# set PYTHON_PATH = c:\Python26
# set PYTHON_LIB  = c:\Python26\libs
PYTHON_PATH= C:\Python32
PYTHON_LIB= C:\Python32\libs
#
# When using the python sources, this will be something like:
# set PYTHON_PATH = c:\yourDir\Python-2.6.1\
# set PYTHON_LIB  = c:\yourDir\Python-2.6.1\PCbuild8\Win32

# check if debug or release
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
  DEBUG_EXT = _d 
} else {
  DEBUG_EXT = 
}

win32:INCLUDEPATH += $(PYTHON_PATH)/PC $(PYTHON_PATH)/include
win32:LIBS += $(PYTHON_LIB)/python$${PYTHON_VERSION}$${DEBUG_EXT}.lib

} else:unix {
# on linux, python-config is used to autodetect Python.
# make sure that you have installed a matching python-dev package.

unix:LIBS += $$system(python$${PYTHON_VERSION}-config --libs)
unix:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$system(python$${PYTHON_VERSION}-config --includes)
}
```

according to this [build link](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/Building.html) I am right
but same errors !!
I don't know what is the problem
thank you in advance =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [page about building it](http://pythonqt.sourceforge.net/Building.html) says it hasn't been tested with Python3 and that some changes may be required.  That's almost certainly the problem you're seeing.

To find out for sure, try again with Python 2.6 or 2.7.  If the build works, then the 163 errors are probably due to Python2/Python3 compatibility changes.

If you have to use Python3 then your only option will be to fix the errors.  Otherwise it's probably easier to just use Python 2.7.

If you decide to fix the Python3 build problems, it'd be nice if you submitted a patch :-)